# Python Process subclass conditional execution

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pywin32

I am currently trying to create a error handling module that contains a Process subclass that handles the display of error messages asynchronously. However, I would only like one instance of a specific error message to be displayed (as opposed to having multiple windows pop up). Here is what I have so far:

```
import win32api
import winsound
from multiprocessing import Process

class Error:
    NetworkImageError, DiskError = range(2)

# This moudle contains the Process subclass handleError. This will create an
# asynchronous process that will create a Windows alert dialog for critical errors.

class handleError(Process):
        def __init__(self, file_name, error_type):
            super(handleError, self).__init__()
            self.error_type = error_type
            self.file_name = file_name

        def run(self):
            title = message = ''

            if self.error_type == Error.NetworkImageError:
                title = 'Network Error'
                message = 'Unable to notify server about the file ' + self.file_name + '. Check your network connection.'
            elif self.error_type == Error.DiskError:
                title = 'IO Error'
                message = 'Unable to read/write the file ' + self.file_name + '. Check your storage drive.'

            winsound.MessageBeep(-1)
            win32api.MessageBox(0, message, title, 0x00001000)
```

I am thinking that there should perhaps be a global (or static?) variable (or array) of some sort that keeps track of the alerts that are currently being shown. So assuming that there can be multiple instances of the handleError Process, how can I show only one instance of each error message?

I.e. If an IO Error alert is currently being shown, subsequent requests to show the same alert will be ignored.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? You want to make sure only one instance of a specific error is displayed, and you mention a way you think you can do it, but you never actually asked a question.

Comment: I have revised my question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: How/where are `handleError` processes created?

Comment: The handleError process in called in a separate module that contains a queue of jobs. If the job throws an exception of some sort (i.e. NetworkError or IOError), a handleError Process will be created to alert the user of the error.

Comment: I suggest a single handleError process, which accepts a `Queue` of `(file_name, error_type)` tuples.  When an error occurs, the handler will do `errorQueue.put( (fname,etype) )`, the handleError process will get it, and display it if it hasn't been displayed before.